# How to put Subtotal in multiple col cells?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

How to put a subtotal in multiple cells?
[image]

```
AggregationSubtotalBuilder totalBase = sbt.sum(total_, config.getColumn("base").getCol());
AggregationSubtotalBuilder member_count = sbt.text("Total Employes :", config.getColumn("code").getCol());               
jrb.subtotalsAtGroupFooter( emp_number_group, member_count, totalBase );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with some tricks

```
Class ComponentPosition 
   private static void recalculateWidth(String name, DRDesignList list, int availableWidth) throws DRException {
for (int i=0;i<list.getListCells().size();i++) {
            DRDesignListCell listCell = list.getListCells().get(i); 
            DRDesignComponent component = listCell.getComponent();
            if (component instanceof DRDesignList){               
               for (DRDesignComponent cp : ((DRDesignList)component).getComponents()){
                  Integer colSpan = colSpans.get( cp.getName() );
                  if (colSpan!=null){                     
                     int w = 0;
                     for (int j=0;j<colSpan;j++){                        
                        w += list.getListCells().get(i+j).getComponent().getWidth();
                        list.getListCells().get(i+j).getComponent().setWidth(0);
                     }   
                     cp.setWidth(w);
                     component.setWidth(w);                                          
                  }                                       
               }            
            }
         }
```

Then `ComponentPosition.colSpans.put(memeber_count.getName(), 3);`